# sbatch binds different jobs to a single core

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, parallel-processing, slurm

We use Slurm resource manager to send jobs to the cluster. Recently, we upgraded the Slurm version from 15 to 18.

Since the upgrade I encounter the following problem:
I consequently send jobs that require single core and should utilize ~100% cpu.
However, when those jobs arrive to the same computing node, it seems that they roughly share a single core. I.e, when the 1st job arrive it gets 100% cpu, when the 2nd arrives they both get 50% etc. etc. Sometimes there are 20 jobs on the same node (it has 24 physical cores) and each get ~5% cpu.

The setup that reproduce the problem is very simple:
The executable is a simple C busy loop that was verified to consume ~100% cpu when run locally.
The script file that I send is:

```
> cat my.sh
#/bin/bash
/path/to/busy_loop
```

The sbatch command is:

```
sbatch -n1 -c1 my.sh
```

Some observations:

- The problem persist whether I launch the job step directly (as above), use mpirun or srun.
- It seems that the problem is related only to collision between jobs, not inside the same job: If I send the job using `sbatch -n2 -c1 my.sh` and inside the script file use `mpirun /path/to/busy_loop`, it seems that every process get 100% cpu. However, if another such job will be sent to the same node, they will share same 2 cores and each of the 4 processes get 50% cpu.
- The previous installation is still available for me on an old cluster. As far as I can assess, it seems that the slurm.conf of both installations is equivalent (and very simple).

I didn't find any reference to a similar problem over the web and every reference or help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different changes in `slurm.conf` the change that solved the problem was adding the line:
`TaskPlugin=task/affinity`

Comment: For some reason, in the previous version of Slurm there was no reason to explicitly specify this parameter.